# dll and pdb aren't created in bin/debug folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build, visual-studio-2017

I have solution with 48 projects. Few days ago I created new project, built it, but dll, dll.config and pdb files didn't appear in the bin/debug folder in my whole solution in my repository. I have no errors after building.

I do not see the difference in settings between this new and my other projects. All others normally appear in bin/debug folder after building. I tried to clean solution, rebuild it, but I still don't have these files.

I use Visual Studio 2017, but in 2019 is the same situation.

I need these files because this is my test that must run on another computer. I tried to copy files from bin folder from this project, but test doesn't work on other computer, it works only in my computer.

How can I fix it?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-view-save-and-configure-build-log-files?view=vs-2019#to-change-the-amount-of-information-included-in-the-build-log View verbose log and you can easily find the right path.

Comment: Hmm, I checked and I don't have my project in Output Item(s) for my whole solution. Other things in verbose log looks the same like for other projects, that work correctly. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I created new branch, new project and have the same situation. I don't have files in debug folder. What should I pay attention to when viewing logs?